# applescript Web Scraping script not working

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, applescript

I am trying to learn how to build a web scraper to improve my productivity at work.  I found a site that gives an example and step by step guide on how to build a rudimentary scraper but when I put the code into my script editor I get the error "the variable input is not defined." number -2753 from "input". the code looks like this:

```
to getInputByClass(theClass, num) -- defines a function with two inputs, theClass and num
    tell application "Safari" --tells AS that we are going to use Safari
        set input to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return input
end getInputByClass

getInputByClass("r", 0)
```

Any help on how to fix the code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The javascript statement is not being resolved - what is the class name "r" supposed to be?

Comment: I don’t really know.  I copied this from a tutorial page

Comment: Then I suppose that would be the issue.  The script works when the page has the specified class, so you would need to decide what class to get, possibly adding error handling if it doesn’t exist.

Comment: Do you know of a good place to walk me through this that also explains things so I understand what I am doing?

Comment: What tutorial were you using?  Are you familiar with scripting and HTML?  If not, that would be a good place to start.